# Symfony FOSUserBundle https in mails

Tags: symfony, ssl, https, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

Symfony 3.4. I have a problem with forcing mailer use only https with URLs in mail such as activation/forgot password mail from FOSBundle, example:

```
message: |
Hello %username%!

To finish activating your account - please visit %confirmationUrl%

This link can only be used once to validate your account.

Regards,
the Team.
```

is there way to force mailer use https for %confirmationUrl% and others? Thanks!

Comment: I think there could be a few solutions. Most easy could be (i didn' t test it) to force the routes that are used to generate full URL's to https. See this page: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/routing/scheme.html. To do that you will have to add your own version of the fosuserbundle routing. You can find the routing files here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/config/routing . Copy them to your own src/AppBundle/Resources/Config bundle and, edit them to make them force https and change app/config/routing.yml to include your own files

Comment: okay i will write an official answer in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the routes -that are used to generate full URL's- to https. See [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/routing/scheme.html).

To do that you will have to add your own version of the fosuserbundle routing. You can find the [routing files here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/config/routing).

Copy them to your **src/AppBundle/Resources/config** bundle directory and edit them to make them force https and change **app/config/routing.yml** to include your own files